# nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_52' - OpenCV 2.5 build

Tags: opencv, build, terminal, nvcc

I cannot compile opencv 2.5 on a red hat 7.1

already tried various cmake options such as :

cmake  -D BUILD_TIFF=ON  -D CUDA_GENERATION=Auto ../ 
cmake -D BUILD_TIFF=ON -D WITH_CUDA=OFF  ../

Here is the terminal output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_opencv_test_videostab
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_opencv_videostab
[ 27%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_cudaoptflow
[ 27%] Generating precomp.hpp
[ 27%] Generating test_precomp.hpp
[ 27%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_videostab_Release.gch
[ 27%] Generating test_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_test_videostab_Release.gch
[ 27%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_cudaoptflow
[ 27%] Processing OpenCL kernels (core)
[ 27%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o
**nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_52'**
**CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o.cmake:206 (message):
  Error generating**
  /home/yioannidis/Downloads/opencv2_5/build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o
```

Comment: I don't think there is an opencv version **2.5**. The latest version (as of now) in the version 2 pipeline is `2.4.13.4 `

Comment: Which version of cuda are you using?

Comment: this is the opencv version I am using : pkg-config --modversion opencv
2.4.5.  Also,  the cude version is :  nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jul_17_21:41:27_CDT_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.12